# C Programming: How to put integers, doubles and strings from user input into 3 seperate arrays?

Tags: c, arrays, string, input, c-strings

I'm trying to create a C program that inputs a txt file and a specific output gets printed.

This is the txt file in the followng format which I will be using, called input.txt:

```
  1 35.026172 OfxDTW
  2 11.881445 sMLZrs
  3 64.033097 sQkGmn
  4 96.968208 Mhbfka
  5 75.157107 yWtcBI
  6 27.852157 svSzwI
  7 38.371393 UGGpRX
  8 54.500524 LOHGPL
  9 45.875275 aAwiSd
 10 18.583704 OYpIiO
```

I want to put the integer, double and the string into 3 seperate arrays, rather than putting an entire line into a single array.

The txt file will be inputted as:

```
 program < input.txt
```

Here is my main program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 10000

int
main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int number[MAX];
    double decimal[MAX];
    char *string[6][MAX];
    char str[6];
    int a;
    double b;
    int i=0,k=0,j=0;
    int ch=0;
    while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (scanf("%d ", &a)==1) {
            number[i] = a;
            i += 1;
        }

        if (scanf("%lf ", &b)==1) {
            decimal[j] = b;
            += 1;
        }

        if (scanf("%s", str)==1) {
            string[6][k]=str;
            k += 1;
        }
    }

    printf("n: %d, ", number[4]);
    printf("d: %lf, ", decimal[4]);
    printf("s: %s", string[6][4]);
    return 0;
}
```

For my output, I just want to print the 5th row of the txt file with the added text:

```
 n: 5, d: 75.157107, s: yWtcBI
```

However, the program isn't printing the correct output.

Does anyone know what is wrong with my program and how I can fix it?

Comment: What output are you getting?

Comment: n: 5, d: 0.000000, s: OYpIiO

Comment: Just FYI, `string[6][k]=str` is wrong for two reasons: First, it's out of range. Arrays in C are 0-base-idexed. So `char *string[6][MAX]` is only addressable on he dominant dimension fro `0..5` inclusive, and `0..(MAX-1)` on the inferior dimension. Your code directly violates that, and in so doing invokes *undefined behavior*. Second, even if that is fixed, that code doesn't save a copy of the string; it saves a copy of the *pointer*. In the end, *all* storage from that instruction results in saving a pointer to the same buffer (`str`).

Comment: Looking up online, it says that I should use a 2d array for inputting strings. The [6] is meant to be length of the string.

Comment: So what should I do to fix this?

Comment: hi @tyytwe, welcome ! one advice: using separate arrays is asking for trouble. When more data is added, you need more arrays. I would declare a struct { } with the values in it.

Comment: Well is it possible to just use arrays, instead of structs?

Comment: Then you should have `char string[MAX][7];` instead.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. But structs are much easier.

Comment: Yes that is possible when the number of columns is fixed and small, but it is also asking for bugs.

Answer (score 1):

I took the libert of simplifying and light tweaking your code

```
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX 10000

int main(void) {
    int number[MAX];
    double decimal[MAX];
    char string[MAX][7];
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
        if (scanf("%d%lf%6s", number+i, decimal+i, string+i)!=3) break;
    }

    if (i > 4) {
        printf("n: %d, d: %f, s: %s\n", number[4], decimal[4], string[4]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```